# How to detect trusted sites using HttpWebRequest in webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-404

> I have a console application for the 2.0 framework in C#, using vs
>   2005. This is weird, the exact same code I have worked on both my pc and the server(using webservice).
>
> When I execute `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` on URL, First one(pc)
>   works well but last one(webservice) returns an error :
>
> ```
> (404) Not Found. The URL is a trusted site. 
> Internet sites and local intranet sites are detected successfully. 
> But trusted sites only could not be detected.
> ```
>
> I don't know why?
>
> This is the code:
>
> ```
> private bool getSiteConnStatus(string url)
> {
>   bool result = true;
>   Uri uri = new Uri(url);
>   try
>   {
>       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);          
>       WebProxy SCProxy = new WebProxy("123.123.123.123");          
>       SCProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();                
>       request.Proxy = SCProxy;          
>
>       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
>       if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
>       {
>           result = false;
>       }
>       response.Close();
>   }
>   catch (Exception ex)
>   {
>       result = false;
>   }
>   return result;
> }
> ```

~~~~~~~~~~

I've solved.

The Proxy information was changed whenever each site called. So I added some lines below.
 [Reference site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx)

```
 private bool getSiteConnStatus(string url)
    {
        bool result = true;
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            ***WebProxy SCProxy;
            if (request.Address.Host == "test.net")
            {
                SCProxy = new WebProxy("111.111.111.111", 8080);
            }
            else
            {
                SCProxy = new WebProxy("123.123.123.123", true);
            }
            request.Proxy = SCProxy;***

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                result = false;
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried hitting the URL in a browser? Have you tried using fiddler or wireshark to look at the request being made?

Comment: "Trusted sites" are an IE phenomenon, not a WebRequest phenomenon. That message may be coming from your Internet Proxy Server.

Comment: I have tried hitting the URL in a browser. No problem.

Comment: I have tried to capture with wireshark. But nothing special.
[ log ]
HTTP GET http://aaa.bbb.com/pages/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
HTTP HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found (text/html)

Comment: I've solved. That's a proxy setting. The proxy uri is changed whenever requested site is changed, So I changed the proxy uri of not founding site.

[Reference site : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx)]

Answer (score 0):

Try Accessing your url from Browser (on-server) - If it works your browser agent is configured to make communication to/from given ports to the outside world.

Check your firewall policies and any specific user-agent strings they are preventing to make connections to the out-side world ?

Also verify your Proxy Authentication , if you try it from the browser (i presume here its IE ) . browser might supply it automatically / NTLM Authentication strings. where your program might not be able to ?

Comment: The thing was that the proxy server ip changed per web sites. So I edited my source code as matching between the proxy server and the website.